# How do I prevent graphite from filling up my primary disk on ubuntu in EC2?

Tags: ubuntu, storage, graphite

I am running [graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) (per reading [this blog by Etsy](http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/)) on an [Ubuntu 10.10 linux install](http://alestic.com/) on EC2. Basically it works, except that my server is constantly exhausting reported free disk space. I say reported free space because rebooting my server reduces the reported consumed space back down to about 2GB. As an attempt to alleviate this problem I symlinked the graphite/storage/whisper folder to /mnt, but to no avail - df still reports:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              8256952   8256952         0 100% /
```

As far as I can tell I am only actually using about 2GB of storage space and all of my whisper data is in fact going to /mnt which has like 400GB of space available.

Can anyone recommend a configuration for graphite that will enable me to avoid having it reportedly exhaust storage on my primary disk? Also, does this issue have something to do with open file descriptors?

UPDATE:

Here is my storage schema:

```
[everything_1min_1day]
priority = 100
pattern = .*
retentions = 60:20160
```

Comment: Without knowing that software existed, I had to reread the title a few times to make sure I wasn't seeing things

Comment: what does your storage-schema.conf look like?

Comment: @Mike I have added my storage schema to the original question

Comment: If you "du -h ./graphite", how much are you storing there and where is the file-system mounted?